# Equivalent of PHP's  'array_splice' in java

Tags: java, php

How can I implement `array_splice()` in java

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 2);
// $input is now array("red", "green")
```

http://php.net/array_splice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java equivalent is `List.subList(int, int)`.

Comment: subList with capital L

Comment: @AlonR - Thanks for catching that. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(sourceArray, start, end);`.

```
String[] anArray = new String[] { "red", "green", "blue", "yellow" };
String[] subset = Arrays.copyOfRange(anArray, 0, 2);
```

Comment: With this approach, changes to `subset` will not appear in `anArray`. With both PHP's `array_splice` and with Java's `sublist`, changes are propagated back to the original array.